# Simple explanation of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to programming and I'm looking for a simple answer to build my foundation of understanding Arrays. I've used google and searched this site.

After a bit of trial and error I get how to make and reference Arrays like thing[3] gets you the fourth thing in the thing array(since 0 is the first). which lets me do something like thing[3].getStupidNumber() to get the StupidNumber of the 4th thing in the thing array.

Then I get to ArrayLists which seem to have much more utility but I cant make logical sense of them like Arrays. When i search I cant find this or word this correctly and thus far everything else I've learned clicked easily.

so say I make an ArrayList thing with 5 things in it. how do i get to the .getStupidNumber() method inside the fourth thing, if possible? I think if I learn this I can learn the rest on my own.

Comment: Note that in Java, the `ArrayList` type will actually allocate a new array and then copy the old contents when you insert a new item, making it not necessarily the best thing to use.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak - hover over the downvote arrow; *research effort*. There's only about 475,000 pages that come up on using arraylist if you google it.

Comment: @jli Only if it needs more room, but how it grows is implementation-dependent and unspecified.

Comment: @DaveNewton if you know the initial capacity then it doesn't, but if you know that then you can just use an array.

Comment: @jli No, if you don't exceed its capacity, but again, capacity and growth are not defined as part of the API.

Comment: @DaveNewton its default capacity it 10, unless you call a different constructor to set the initial capacity. So effectively you have to know the initial capacity.

Comment: @jli No, you don't, but it helps to have an upper bound. You said it'll allocate a new array etc. when you add a new item, which isn't generally true--it happens when you exceed its capacity (although again, implementation dependent). Saying it does it "when you add an item" is misleading, because it's rarely true. It *may*, but in general, won't. And you can call ensureCapacity to avoid reallocs if you know you're going to dump a lot into it anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton what I'm saying is that if you know how much to ensure, you can just make an array of that size..

Comment: @jli Well, your original statement reads quite differently from that, but perhaps somehow I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` ( and `List` in general ) has a positional `get` method, which acts essentially the same as `[]` array operator.

```
ArrayList<StupidThing> list = ...;

list.get(3).getStupidNumber( );
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have a class called StupidThing

```
class StupidThing {
    int getStupidNumber(){return 1;}
}

List list = new ArrayList(); 
// This list represents a list of Object. It can hold only object. 
StupidThing stupidThing = new StupidThing();
```

and you want to have an array of StupidThings. We can add stupidThing to the array.

```
list.add(stupidThing);
```

Be aware that list represents an array of Objects. Therefore, list.get(0) will return the first stupidThing as an Object. In order to call StupidThing's method, you need to downcast the returned object to StupidThing;

```
int stupidNumber = ( (StupidThing) (list.get(0)) ).getStupidNumber();
```

If you don't like "downcast", you can use a list of StupidThing instead.

```
List<StupidThing> list = new ArrayList<StupidThing>(); 
// Now list can only hold instances of StupidThing  
StupidThing stupidThing = new StupidThing();
list.add(stupidThing); 
int stupidNumber = list.get(0).getStupidNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about genericity. 
[see Generics in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Comment: Thanks, kinda. But you sorta need to learn about answering questions properly. I asked for a simple answer to something I specified in the question and you give me a link.

Maybe you weren't trying to be rude and I'm not trying to be either.

Comment: If I give you an answer so you'll only know how to do it with a little piece of code. And next time, if the problem is slightly different, you'll ask again. So I think that giving you the technical term about what you need to do/know is one of the possible answers. I was just trying to help you because I know it's hard to look for something when you don't know how it's called.